# Duplicate filenames in a directory replaces the old one

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiohttp

I have this code:

```
async with aiohttp.get('http://httpbin.org/image/png') as r:
            if r.status == 200:
                img = await r.read()
                with open('Images/' + 'img.png', 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(img)
                    print('Done downloading!')
```

There seems to be a problem. The code works fine but when I try to download another image and if it has the same filename then it will replace the old image with the new one. I don't want it to do this which is why I need to know of a a way to check for duplicates and try to rename the second one but keep the first one the same if they both have the same filename.

Comment: Append a random number at the end of your file names.

Comment: Solved it, thanks.